# preserve existing code for arbitrary scalafmt settings

Tags: scala, scalafmt

I'm trying to gently introduce scalafmt to a large existing codebase and I want it to make virtually no changes except for a handful of noncontroversial settings the whole team can agree on.

With some settings like `maxColumn` I can override the default of `80` to something absurd like `5000` to have no changes. But with other settings I have to make choices that will modify the existing code like with `continuationIndent.callSite`. The setting requires a number which would aggressively introduce changes on the first run on our codebase.

Is there anything I can do in my scalafmt config to preserve all my code except for a few specific settings?

EDIT: I will also accept suggestions of other tools that solve the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [project.includeFilters](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#project):

> Configure which source files should be formatted in this project.
>
> ```
> # manually include files to format. 
> project.includeFilters = [
>  regex1   
>  regex2 
> ]
> ```

For example, say we have project structure with `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, etc. packages like so

```
someProject/src/main/scala/com/example/foo/*.scala
someProject/src/main/scala/com/example/bar/*.scala
someProject/src/main/scala/com/example/baz/qux/*.scala
...
```

Then the following `.scalafmt.conf`

```
project.includeFilters = [
  "foo/.*"
]
continuationIndent.callSite = 2
...
```

will format only files in `foo` package. Now we can proceed to gradually introduce formatting to the codebase package-by-package

```
project.includeFilters = [
  "foo/.*"
  "bar/.*"
]
continuationIndent.callSite = 2
...
```

or even file-by-file

```
project.includeFilters = [
  "foo/FooA\.scala"
  "foo/FooB\.scala"
]
continuationIndent.callSite = 2
...
```

Comment: This is cool and I didn't know you could do that. But I'm really looking for a way to just enforce one or two of the scalafmt settings on all the files.